# Как создать список с помощью Value Tuple

Tags: c#, tuple

Добавил через `NuGet` `System.ValueTuple`. Как можно создать список `List` с 4 параметрами double, добавить элемент и вывести на экран в консоль.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Поступайте как с обычными данными:

```
var list = new List<(double, double, double, double)>();
var item = (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4);
list.Add(item);
Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("(" + item.Item1 + ", " + item.Item2 + ")"); //и т.д.
```

Как верно подметил @Grundy [`ValueTuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetuple(v=vs.110).aspx) - это структура.

Вот [здесь](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-value-tuple-in-c-sharp-7-0/) хорошо описано как с ней работать.

Кстати, можно еще записать как *"namedTuple"*:

```
var namedTuple = (Length: 1.13, Height: 2.11, Width: 3.14);
/*
* что примечательно, можно работать и как в 1м варианте:
* var length = namedTuple.Item1;
* и вот так:
*/
var height = namedTuple.Height;
```

Comment: Просто, хотел с таким синтаксисом написать в итоге, чтобы без Tuple. Но удивился, что синтаксис c# не пропускает, хоть установил всё) А так, спасибо, буду тогда таким образом всё делать)

Comment: @Fresto, вероятно ты хотел `List<(double,double,double,double)>` и `var item = (1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4);`. Но на сколько я понимаю, это **НЕ** `ValueTuple`

Comment: @Grundy все верно, спасибо за замечание

Comment: @Ep1demic, кстати, `ValueTuple` - это не класс, а структура

Comment: @Grundy что значит - это не ValueTuple? А что же тогда?

Comment: @Grundy да, хотел именно это, но синтаксис почему-то c# не распознал такой)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а не знаю, мне казалось они как-то по другому назывались. Это все-таки ValueTuple? и они действительно struct?

Comment: @Grundy да, так и есть

Comment: @PavelMayorov на момент как Вы увидели мой ответ, я его уже скорее всего исправил, по совету Grundy =)